# Stitching Image on iOS

Tags: ios4, ios5

Is there any hint for stitching images (2 at a time) on iOS ? Any sample codes ?

The OpenCV for iOS can do the job ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to stitch images, you can try this:

https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVStitch